# Yii - Best way to make minification configurable

Tags: php, inheritance, yii

I am using [minscript](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/minscript/) extension for Javascript and CSS minification on my site. I have the following code in my protected/config/main.php

```
'clientScript'=>array(
    'class'=>'ext.minScript.components.ExtMinScript',
)
```

In one of the modules I need custom implementation of CClientScript class. So I made a new class and derived it from ExtMinScript, like this.

```
class BaseClientScript extends ExtMinScript
```

In the module initialization code, I use setComponent to "overwrite" the "clientScript" component from main configuration. Thus I get the minification implementation from ExtMinScript and my implementation in BaseClientScript.

If I want to disable minification in the module, I change the code to derive BaseClientScript from CClientScript.

```
class BaseClientScript extends CClientScript
```

Now I want minification to be configurable in the main configuration. (protected/config/main.php)

I can make two classes, one deriving from CClientScript and other from ExtMinScript. (BaseClientScript and BaseMinClientScript)
I don't want to do that, as that would mean that I have duplicate my custom client-script implementation in two classes.

Is there a better way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a technique like this:

```
 define('MinClientScriptClass', 'CClientScript');
```

when you want to use minification in protected/config/main.php

and write this in BaseClientScript:

```
if (defined('MinClientScriptClass')) {

    class MinClientScriptClass extends CClientScript {}

} else {

    class MinClientScriptClass extends ExtMinScript {}
}

class BaseClientScript extends MinClientScriptClass
```

**NOTE**: When you want to disable minification just comment the define in main config. Or use config params in main.php, and config true/false value check in if above.